# Существуют ли трехмерные массивы в Pascal, как ими пользоваться?

Tags: массивы, pascal

Существует ли трехмерный массив Pascal?
Если да, то приведите пример использования, пожалуйста.

```
program maasss;
var a: array[1..10,1..10,1..10] of byte;
begin
writeln(a[5,5,5]);
end.
```

Результат 0. Ничего не понимаю

Comment: @insolor, ну 3х мерный массив я еще как-то могу представить, не мог бы ты мне показать картинку 4х и 5х мерного массива?)))

Comment: Да, 2-х мерный массив, это 2D(квадрат), трехмерный - 3D(куб), а четырехмерный - 4D(четыре измерения???)

Comment: @Gorets, 5-мерный массив - это всего лишь двумерный массив 3-мерных массивов :)

Comment: кэп, а 5д - это 5 измерений? непредставляеться... =)

Comment: @insolor - схемку сделай пожалуйста, для подтверждения

Comment: @Gorets, можно хоть 20-мерный нарисовать при желании :)

Comment: Если массив двухмерный то понятно, ищется по первой координате строчка, а по второй место в строке, а если массив 20-мерный, как выразился ReinRaus, то как организовывается поиск по массиву?

Comment: Чтобы не вызвать у себя в голове разрыв шаблона представляйте себе 6-мерный массив как 3-мерный массив 3-мерных массивов.   
9-мерный как 6-мерный массив 3-мерных массивов и т.д.

Comment: Аналогично, вы просто называете все "строкой" и "столбцом" - словами, характеризующими двумерное пространство.

Называйте 1,2,3...N - измерением. И будет вам счастье: координата первого измерения, координата второго, координата третьего... и так далее.

В паскале имеем:

    l: array[0..5, 0..5, 0..5, 0..5, 0..5] of Integer;

Comment: @Dex так все таки почему
procedure Fnord;
const
  N = 42;
type
  T = array [0..N-1] of array [0..N-1] of array [0..N-1] of Integer;
var
  A: T;
  
begin
  { ... }
end;
результат будет 0

Comment: @platinumsemen, что почему? Вопрос сформулируйте.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот еще наглядный пример, для чего можно использовать многомерные массивы. На самом деле, конечно, для этого сейчас используют БД. Допустим, вы хотите собрать статистику по участникам форумов. Сначала у вас есть два показателя: форумы и города. С помощью двумерного массива вы сможете описать то, на каком форуме из каких городов сколько зарегистрировалось пользователей.

[image]

Дальше вы хотите описать пользователей более подробное. Например, по роду деятельности. Чтобы модно было узнать, сколько участников из города A, зарегистрировавшихся на форуме А, является представителями группы С:

[image]

Получился трехмерный массив. Самое простое, что приходит в голову далее - это определить всё то же самое, только разделяя по времени. То есть отдельно для 2012 года, 2011, 2010, и т.д. Получится 4-х мерный массив:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> 'Результат 0. Ничего не понимаю'

так это же ясно.При создании новых `integer` их значение поумолчанию равно `0` а при создании `string` их значение по умолчанию равно `''` т.е пустой строке.Это же самые элементарные правила!

Comment: так это все в 3=х мерном массиве

Comment: хоть в миллионмерном его основа ято цыфры - значит по умолчанию значение меры масива = 0! И за что минусуете? кого надо минусовать так это автора вопроса за глупость которую он спрашивает! Имхо

Answer (score 2):

Существует. И четырехмерный тоже. И даже пятимерный, но вряд ли такие массивы где-то используются на практике. Объявляются/используются совершенно аналогично 2-мерным.

В отличие от бесконечных пространственных измерений, массивы конечны, поэтому ничто не мешает расположить "рядом" друг с другом.

Пример кода:

```
program maasss;
  var a: array[1..10,1..10,1..10,1..10,1..10] of byte;
begin
  a[1,2,3,4,5]:=123;
  write(a[1,2,3,4,5]);
end.
```

Не знаю как там в Turbo Pascal, а во Free Pascal отлично работает: http://ideone.com/Obsal

Пример многомерного массива "из жизни". Допустим книга - трехмерный массив букв (3 координаты - страница, строка, номер буквы в строке). Теперь берем стопку книг - это уже 4-мерный массив букв (еще одно измерение - номер книги в стопке). Ставим несколько стопок книг рядом - 5 измерений. Ставим стопки в несколько рядов - 6 измерений. Грузим книги стопками в грузовики - появилось 6 измерение - номер грузовика. Ну и так далее.

Comment: И все-таки, подтвердите изображением ваш ответ, хотя бы пятимерный массив

Comment: Возьмите любой пример по OLAP, многомерным БД. Оно вам подойдет.

Comment: Program1.pas(2) : Ожидалось of
ошибка компилятора для пятимерного массива

Comment: Понял, моя вина

Answer (score 0):

Трехмерный массив на Pascal:

```
procedure Fnord;
const
  N = 42;
type
  T = array [0..N-1] of array [0..N-1] of array [0..N-1] of Integer;
var
  A: T;
begin
  { ... }
  A[5,8,2] := 86;
  { ... }
end;
```

Comment: Program1.pas(12) : Ожидалось begin

Answer (score 0):

> Результат 0. Ничего не понимаю

ноль и будет, присвоений для элементов массива не было, поэтому все элементы равны нулю. Если хотите, увидеть хоть какой то результат, сделайте так.

```
program maasss;
var a: array[1..10,1..10,1..10] of byte;
begin
a[5,5,5]:=23; {этому элементу присвоено значение 23, остальные элементы равны нулю}
writeln(a[5,5,5]);
end.
```